# Qt4 to Qt5 on macOS: lost window list in mac toolbar icon

Tags: macos, qt4, qt5, toolbar, macos-sierra

When I open multiple windows in my Qt4 app on mac, the toolbar lists them: [image]

When I do the same in Qt5, the toolbar doesn't list any windows my application has:

[image]

I've looked around but couldn't find an option. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in Qt, confirmed in other applications as well: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-59433.